# ToggleButton hover and click behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controls, controltemplate

I created a ContentTemplate and Style for the ToggleButton which looks like the one you know from Microsoft's WebMatrix.

However, it's not always possible to click and the hover effect isn't shown too.
I figured out that the click/hover area appears when I'm hovering over the icon or the text of my button.

[image: Hover and click don't work]

[image: Hover and click work]

Once hovered It's possible to get back to right with the mouse and the hover doesn't disappear (as it should).

Here's the important part of the code:

```
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationButton}" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="_btn_Buchungen" Click="_btn_Buchungen_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Buchungen}" Width="16" Height="16" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Buchungen" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ToggleButton>
```

The ControlTemplate and Styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="NavigationButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Name="OuterBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" >
                            <Border Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" >
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonInnerBHover}" />
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonOuterBHover}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"  Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonInnerBHover}" />
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource ButtonOuterBHover}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" Direction="270" ShadowDepth="1" Color="White" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```

The ToggleButton's hover should be shown when you are mouse over the full width of the button itself and should also be clickable.

I tried t fix it with different properties like horizontal stretching and IsHitTestVisible but I didn't get it yet. **Any idea?**

Already saw this thread and tried different things with the solution but couldn't figure it out. [Problem with the mouse click on toggleButton in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821643/problem-with-the-mouse-click-on-togglebutton-in-wpf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `Background` of the outermost control in the template to `Transparent`, that way it should hit-test, no matter what the content is.

Comment: Seems you are some kind of mastermind. It works like a charm and It would never have occurred to me.

Comment: Yep, using `{x:Null}` does weird stuff with the hit-testing, I try to avoid it at all costs!

Comment: @Kolky: I wouldn't call it weird, it just doesn't hit-test at all.